# Random password generated by phpmyadmin not satisfying

Tags: 20.04, mysql, password, phpmyadmin

I am trying to install phpmyadmin in ubuntu 20.04.

I ran `sudo apt update && sudo apt install phpmyadmin php-mbstring` to first update the system and then download it. Then it prompted me to enter a password that I did. for consideration, I entered **qwertY!1** which is of 8 digits, has small, capital letters, special character and a number which should satisfy the needs. *BUT IT DIDN'T*.

[The Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dz0dI.png)

When I checked the requirements by running `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';` in mysql, I got this:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';
+--------------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                        | Value |
+--------------------------------------+-------+
| validate_password.check_user_name    | ON    |
| validate_password.dictionary_file    |       |
| validate_password.length             | 8     |
| validate_password.mixed_case_count   | 1     |
| validate_password.number_count       | 1     |
| validate_password.policy             | LOW   |
| validate_password.special_char_count | 1     |
+--------------------------------------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can anybody suggest something? Please help.....

**EDIT:** I also tried leaving the password section blank as it says "If Left blank, a random password will be generated". But that didn't worked too, It says the password it generated didn't satisfied the needs. After some time, I tried leaving it blank again, then it promted to re-enter the password and  i again pressed enter, then it said password missmatch.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37762895/mysql-cannot-grant-privilege-to-user-getting-error-error-1819-hy000-your-pa

Comment: Read the docs that came with the packages (use `dpkg -L packagename` to find them) to find their password policy.